# concurrentConsumers not created right away from beginning

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I am using Camel in a Spring-Boot application to route from AMQ-Queue. Messages from this queue will be sent to a REST-Webservice. It is already working with this code line:

`from("amq:queue:MyQueue").process("jmsToHttpProcessor").to(uri);`

My uri looks like this:

```
http4://localhost:28010/application/createCustomer
```

Now I have the requirement that the routing to the Webservice should be done parallely:

In order to achive that, I configured concurrentConsumers in JmsConfiguration as follows:

```
    @Bean
    public JmsComponent amq(@Qualifier("amqConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory amqConnectionFactory, AMQProperties amqProperties) {
        JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration = new JmsConfiguration(amqConnectionFactory);
        jmsConfiguration.setConcurrentConsumers(50);
        jmsConfiguration.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(50);

        return new JmsComponent(jmsConfiguration);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory amqConnectionFactory(AMQProperties amqProperties) throws Exception {
        ConnectionFactoryParser parser = new ConnectionFactoryParser();
        ConnectionFactory returnValue = parser.newObject(parser.expandURI(amqProperties.getUrl()), "amqConnectionFactory");
        return returnValue;
    }
```

It is working as expected, BUT not right away from the beginning.  I have the phenomenon:

1. I have 100 messages in the ActiveMQ queue
2. I start my Spring application
3. Camel creates only 1 thread consuming 1 message after the previous one gets response
4. I observe that the amount of messages in queue only decreasing slowly(99.... 98... 97... 96...)
5. I am filling the queue with new 100 messages
6. NOW the  concurrent consumers are being created as I can observe that the messages decreasing rapidly.

Does someone have any idea, why the concurrentConsumers is not working right away from the beginning?

Comment: try to set `asyncConsumer=true` (it is false by default)

Comment: Have you set the message prefetch?  Try setting the message prefetch on the AMQ broker (or in the client URL) to 0 or 1.

Answer (score -1):

I tried the advices.  Unfortunately they dont change the behaviour.  I found out, that the problem is that Camel already starts consuming the messages from the queue before the Spring boot application is startet.  I can observe this from the log:

```
2021-04-01T20:26:33,901 INFO  (Camel (CamelBridgeContext) thread #592 - JmsConsumer[MyQueue]) [message]; ...
2021-04-01T20:26:33,902 INFO  (Camel (CamelBridgeContext) thread #592 - JmsConsumer[MyQueue]) [message]; ...
2021-04-01T20:26:33,915 INFO  (main) [AbstractConnector]; _; Started ServerConnector@5833f5cd{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:23500}
2021-04-01T20:26:33,920 INFO  (main) [BridgeWsApplication]; _; Started BridgeWsApplication in 12.53 seconds (JVM running for 13.429)
```

In this case, only one consumer with thread #592 is consuming all the messages.

In fact, if I start my Spring application first, and then fill the queue with messages, then concurrentConsumers will be used:

```
2021-04-01T20:30:20,159 INFO  (Camel (CamelBridgeContext) thread #594 - JmsConsumer[MyQueue]) 
2021-04-01T20:30:20,159 INFO  (Camel (CamelBridgeContext) thread #599 - JmsConsumer[MyQueue]) 
2021-04-01T20:30:20,178 INFO  (Camel (CamelBridgeContext) thread #593 - JmsConsumer[MyQueue]) 
2021-04-01T20:30:20,204 INFO  (Camel (CamelBridgeContext) thread #564 - JmsConsumer[MyQueue])
```

In this case, messages are being consumed from concurrentConsumers parallely.

In order to solve the problem, I tried setting autoStartUp to false in my RouteBuilder component:

```
    @Override
    public void configure() {

        CamelContext context = getContext();
        context.setAutoStartup(false);

        // My Route

    }
```

In my naive thinking, I let Camel starting after the Spring boot is started and running:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(BridgeWsApplication.class, args);

        SpringCamelContext camel = (SpringCamelContext) context.getBean("camelContext");
        camel.start();
        try {
            camel.startAllRoutes();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, this does not change the behaviour.  There must be a configuration to let Camel starts after Spring is started.